# Submit button not aligning with input

Tags: html, css

I'm making a search bar with a submit button. Whenever I link the input box via a class to my css document, it misaligns the box and button.

Here's what I mean:
[What I Have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spZKP.png)

When I remove the class, it re-aligns the box and button but removes my formatting.

This is what I need, but with formatting:

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVA8q.png)

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="search">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" class="search">
<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.search {
    padding: 7.5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    float: right;
}
```

It should align the search box to the right of the border as well, like this:

[Formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8CxD.png)

How do I fix this?

Apologies if I've not explained it very well, so let me know if you need clarification.

Thanks!

Comment: Use flexbox. But without a [mcve], it's difficult to tell you how to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

you should put a id in the button and then recadre it in the css.

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox:

```
.search {
  display: flex;
  padding: 7.5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  float: right;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.fa-search {
  width: 40px; //or fit-content or some other sizes
}
```

for direction of your elements you can do many things but you should read [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) about flexbox and its details.
Or [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).